# Find Unknown Vector from Cross/Dot Products

Tags: vectors, physics

[image: Solution given by manual]

I'm working on a question in a Mechanics textbook that reads:

Assume that two vectors A and B are known. Let $C$ be an unknown vector such that $\vec{A} \cdot \vec{C} = u$ is a known quantity and $\vec{A} \times \vec{C} = \vec{B}$. Find $\vec{C}$ in terms of $\vec{A}$, $\vec{B}$, $\vec{u}$, and the magnitude of $\vec{A}$.

I had trouble figuring this one out and looked at the solution, and after puzzling it over for a while most everything makes sense to me except the terms that are added to the $C_x$ and $C_y$ terms. I see that they reduce to unit vectors so I can tell that their purpose is to correct the orientation of the components, because they don't depend on the $x$ and $y$ axes but on vectors given in the problem. My question is, why exactly those terms? Why does the $C_x$ component go in the $\vec{A}$ direction, and the $C_y$ component go in the $\vec{B} \times \vec{A}$ direction? How can this be determined from the problem?

Comment: It seems they CHOOSE the coordinate system that way. Let the $x$ axis be in the direction of $\vec{A}$, and the $z$ axis be in the direction of $\vec{B}$. Then the $xy$ plane is perpendicular to $\vec{B}$, so it must contain $\vec{C}$.

Comment: $\vec A \times \vec C = \vec B$ gives you a single line of candidate $\vec C$'s, with direction vector $\vec A$. Along with $\vec A \cdot \vec C = u$, this fixes the position of $\vec C$ completely.

Comment: Hey Arthur could you explain that a little more? Starting to get it but need some more clarification. Why does A X C = B mean that C must have direction vector A?